# running multiple counts and joining the results

Tags: sql, hive, grouping, counting

I am trying to do some spot checks on my data by counting the rows in the partitions, counting the amount of 'uses' I see for each day, and counting the amount of values I see for each day.

I was able to get a previous version of the below query to work before but I must have changed something without realizing it:

```
src as
(
   select partition_date_column, count(*) as src_row_count
   from database.table
   where partition_date_column > '2016-01-01' 
   group by partition_date_column
)

,
pst as
(
  select timestamp_pst as datevalue, count(*) as timestamp_row_count
  from database.table
  where partition_date_column > '2016-01-01'
  and timestamp_pst between '2016-01-01' and '2017-07-01'
  group by timestamp_pst
),

users as
(
  select timestamp_pst as user_datevalue, count(*) as user_count
  from database.table
  where partition_date_column > '2016-01-01'
  and timestamp_pst between '2016-01-01' and '2017-07-01'
  and filter_column in ('filterA', 'filterB')
  group by timestamp_pst
)

select datevalue as dayval, src_row_count, timestamp_row_count, user_count
from pst
left join src
on datevalue = partition_date_column
left join users
on datevalue = user_datevalue
order by dayval;
```

I am not clear as to what formatting error I made to cause Hive to not recognize this. I also feel there is likely a better way to count these three items even though one is grouped on a different column.

Comment: Are you getting an error? What is it not doing? Show some sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was missing the "WITH" at the beginning of the code that allowed for multiple select statements like this.

```
With src as
(
   select partition_date_column, count(*) as src_row_count
   from database.table
   where partition_date_column > '2016-01-01' 
   group by partition_date_column
)

,
pst as
(
  select timestamp_pst as datevalue, count(*) as timestamp_row_count
  from database.table
  where partition_date_column > '2016-01-01'
  and timestamp_pst between '2016-01-01' and '2017-07-01'
  group by timestamp_pst
),

users as
(
  select timestamp_pst as user_datevalue, count(*) as user_count
  from database.table
  where partition_date_column > '2016-01-01'
  and timestamp_pst between '2016-01-01' and '2017-07-01'
  and filter_column in ('filterA', 'filterB')
  group by timestamp_pst
)

select datevalue as dayval, src_row_count, timestamp_row_count, user_count
from pst
left join src
on datevalue = partition_date_column
left join users
on datevalue = user_datevalue
order by dayval;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select      pe.val  as dt

           ,count(case when pe.pos = 0 then 1 end)  as src_row_count

           ,count
            (
                case  
                    when    pe.pos = 1 
                        and pe.val between date '2016-01-01' and date '2017-07-01' 
                    then    1 
                end
            ) as    timestamp_row_count 

           ,count
            (
                case  
                    when    pe.pos = 1 
                        and pe.val between date '2016-01-01' and date '2017-07-01' 
                        and filter_column in ('filterA', 'filterB')
                    then    1 
                end
            ) as    user_count

from        database.table  t
            lateral view posexplode (array(partition_date_column,timestamp_pst)) pe

where       partition_date_column > date '2016-01-01' 

group by    pe.val
```